# Android Studio: Elements doesn't react to interactions (but only in Emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have made a simple Android-UI. Actually I started with the spinner. The button I added only for counterchecking, after the spinner didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:entries="@array/months"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:text="Test ..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.mizech.playground

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Testing 123 ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The strings.xml (although I think it isn't relevant):

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Playground</string>
    <string-array name="months">
        <item>January</item>
        <item>February</item>
        <item>March</item>
        <item>April</item>
        <item>May</item>
        <item>June</item>
        <item>July</item>
        <item>August</item>
        <item>September</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

The emulator is like frozen. Neither the spinner nor the button react to any interaction.

[image: Android GUI]

On a physical device all is fine. The spinner expands it's list when clicked. The button works as well.

**What can be the cause, that the emulator behaves suddenly that way? How can it be fixed?**

I have used this virtual device for some time. The described problems came out of the sudden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your minsdk and maxsdk versions are not matching with the emulators minsdk and maxsdk.